# mb_stripos returns incorrect value

Tags: php, multibyte

I am in the process of converting my work environment from ISO-8859-1 encoding to UTF-8.  I have modified the php.ini to accommodate for this change.  If I run `mb_internal_encoding()`, it confirms that it is in fact, UTF-8.

However, I am getting an unexpected result when running the following code:

```
$content = 'eéss';

$substr_pos = mb_stripos($content,'ss');
print_r($substr_pos);
```

`mb_stripos()` is returning 1, when I would expect it to return 2.  Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Can you saved the file with encode UTF-8?

Comment: Works fine here.  http://codepad.viper-7.com/wpgDgs  Assuming internal encoding is UTF-8 maybe try an `iconv()` on the content.  Probably not what you think it is.

Comment: @Laxus, it's embarrassing, but that's all it was, I had forgotten to save the file itself in UTF-8 encoding.  If you want to submit this as an answer, I'll mark is correct.

Comment: Don't worry. Glad to have been helpful. :)